# Saving fragment's view state

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use navigation component and I faced a pretty interesting problem with fragments: whenever I open fragment B from fragment A and then go back to fragment A, fragment A's view state is lost. I mean the view is being created again. The same thing happens if I use `FragmentTransaction` instead of navigation component. When I detach the fragment and then attach again, the view is being created again. Is there any possible way I can prevent the view from being destroyed or is there any way I can save the state of the view?

**UPDATE**

I wrote a simple code to demonstrate this behavior:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navHostView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navHostView) as NavHostFragment?
        val navController = navHostFragment!!.navController
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.navigation_main)
    }
}
```

The navigation itself:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
    android:name="com.sever.fragmentviewtest.FragmentA"
    android:label="FragmentA"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
    android:name="com.sever.fragmentviewtest.FragmentB"
    android:label="FragmentB"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
</navigation>
```

**Fragment A**

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

private var shouldSetText = true

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
        retainInstance = true

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)

        if (shouldSetText) { // Will be called only once
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTest).text = "Some text"
            shouldSetText = false
        }

        view.rootView.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

**Fragment B**

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false)

        view.rootView.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigateUp()
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

**Important**

The FragmentA's onCreateView is being called whenever I navigate back from FragmentB. And if I made some changes to FragmentA's views (like set text to a `TextView`) - they are lost after popping back stack from FragmentB. I tried to use `navigateUp` - the behavior is the same. And also `retainInstance` have not helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: The View being created again is totally different from the View's state not being saved and restored - fragments already automatically save and restore the View's state. Please include your code and what views are losing their state.

Comment: are you showing a list? in that case, you should use ViewModel to holds the list data

Comment: @ianhanniballake I updated the question with code and more explanations

Comment: @Erselan Khan I updated the code)

Comment: @AlexanderKucherenko Fragments' views *are destroyed and recreated by design*. This is the way it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Martin Marconcini I understand that) But the question is is there any way of saving views state? Like is it possible for the view to restore the state after being recreated?

Comment: You haven't posted anything about what Views have "lost their state". For example, if you have an `EditText` with an `android:id`, you'll see that you can type text in that, navigate to another fragment, and hit the system back button to go back to your fragment. Despite the `EditText` being recreated, the **state** is restored and your text is still there. Please include what **specific views** you believe are not restoring their state.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I've updated the FragmentA's code. Basically, I have a TextView and it has an android:id. I set it's text only once in onCreateView. After I navigate back from FragmentB - the TextView is empty (just the way it is in the xml file)

Comment: And if you do the same thing with an `EditText`, do you see the text saved?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, the text is being saved in this case. What can I do to achieve the same behavior with other views? Like TextView, RecyclerView (maybe layout manager's state)?

Comment: RecyclerViews already save and restore their state, along with any other stateful view.